How to know if tab is hidden or shown in Antd library?

As you can see from the above screenshot, Tabs from Tab-17 are hidden.
But How can we know that in Antd library?

What are you trying to do?

Basically, I had design that only renders Icon in dropdown menu tabs, so wanted to know if there is a way to know if tab is rendering inside dropdown or not.

Buy I achieved that by rendering only few tabs (Tab0 - Tab16) and put rest tabs to Dropdown item and render that dropdown as last tab.
